# Inversion Formula for Asymptotic Behaviour

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Suppose that for some functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we have the following relationship
$$\sum_{n=1}^{x} f(n) \sim g(x)$$
or in limit notation
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{x} f(n)}{g(x)} =1 $$
Is there a way to retrieve asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$, i.e. can we find a function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x) \sim h(g(x))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the asymptotic behavior of $f$ is not determined by the asymptotic behavior of its partial sums. Loosely speaking the problem is that the summation averages out oscillatory behavior.

A natural source of examples of this behavior is functions coming from number theory; for example, the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate) $\varphi(n)$ has the property that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \varphi(k) \sim \frac{3n^2}{\pi^2}$$

which is also true of the function $\frac{6n}{\pi^2}$, but it is not true that $\varphi(n) \sim \frac{6n}{\pi^2}$; in fact $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n}$ does not exist, and we have $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = 1$  (by taking $n$ to be prime) but $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n} = 0$ (by taking $n$ to be the product of the first $k$ primes and letting $k \to \infty$).